# How to render the response body in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have a simple GET API. When I click "Try it out" and then "Execute" in Swagger UI, I can see the request reaching the server and getting processed successfully with HTTP status code 200 - ascertained by looking into the server logs.

I would like to see the response body in Swagger UI. What addition or change needs to be done to the OpenAPI YAML spec? I'm using OpenAPI 3.0.3.

Comment: Swagger UI always displays the response body and headers after "try it out" if the response was actually received, as you can see e.g. in the https://petstore.swagger.io demo. How does the UI look after you click "Execute"? Are there any errors in the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Helen - Thanks for the pointers, I appreciate. I have overcome the issue, see my below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By enabling CORS in my flask app, I have managed to overcome the issue ...

From shell prompt ...

```
pip install -U flask-cors
```

Inside app.py ...

```
...
from flask_cors import CORS
...
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
...
```